# TikZ 3d parametric plot on top of 2d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, 3d

I am trying to add a 3d parametric plot of a function on top of 2d axes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
%% axes
\draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] ( 0,-1) -- (0,1);
%% lightcone
\draw[->] (-1,-1,0) -- ( 3,3,0);
\draw[->] ( 1,-1,0) -- (-3,3,0);
%
\begin{axis}
    [
    axis lines=center,
    ticks=none,
    view = {15}{35}
    ]
\addplot3 [no markers,domain = -1:0]
    ( {0}, {x}, {cos(cosh(11*x))}  );
\end  {axis}
%
\end  {tikzpicture}

\end  {document}
```

The function I want to plot is

```
cos( a*exp(x) )
```

Also, when I try to add a pgf "Axis", it does not overlay the axis on top of my image, rather -- off to the side

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, you are right -- I benefit from code-complete questions and answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know the solution to the actual question, I achieved my goal in the following way:

(I did not use anything fancy -- just regular TikZ:)

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1.0]
%
% axes
\draw[->] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0);
% lightcone
\draw[->] (-3,-3,0) -- (3,3,0);
\draw[->] (3,-3,0) -- (-3,3,0);
%
% 3d parametric plot
\draw[domain=-1:-0.02,smooth,variable=\t,white,very thick,double=black] plot(0,{cos(( 6*ln(-\t) ) r) },7*\t);
\draw[domain=0.02:1,smooth,variable=\t,white,very thick,double=black] plot(0,{0.2*cos(( 6*ln(\t) ) r) },7*\t);
%
\end   {tikzpicture}
```

P.S.
I think the reason I was not able to compose `cos` and `exp` was because my domain was way too large for evaluating the exponential function: `-360:360`

Comment: regular TikZ is fancy! here is a kind of complete code. However, I do not understand your question as well as your own answer ^^ `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[variable=\t,double=black,smooth]
\draw[->] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0);
% lightcone
\draw[->] (-3,-3,0) -- (3,3,0);
\draw[->] (3,-3,0) -- (-3,3,0);
% 3d parametric plot
\draw[thick,red]  plot[domain=-1:-0.02] (0,{cos((6*ln(-\t)) r)},7*\t);
\draw[thick,blue] plot[domain=0.02:1] (0,{0.2*cos(( 6*ln(\t)) r)},7*\t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`